# Is my understanding of Microsoft data interaction correct?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2010, sharepoint

I am creating diagram to help our Tier 1 and 2 staff understand the flow of data from ADUC as well as other databases in our company. I'm trying to get a good grasp of how a users data is accessed by various Microsoft applications.

The idea behind this is so that if a user has a problem with data somewhere (SharePoint for example) our support staff can follow a workflow to know where SharePoint is getting it's data from and where there may be a problem.

From what I have been told, AD and Exchange are the same data table. SharePoint then accesses this data. The Global Address List also accesses this same data table as well.

Is that correct?

In the beginning I thought AD and Exchange are two different databases that interacted with each other where SharePoint pulled from AD and the GAL and OCS pulled from Exchange.

Comment: `1.` ADUC is a management console for managing users, computers, OU's, etc., etc. ADUC doesn't have data. Rather it is used to access and manage the "data" in the Active Directory database, ntds.dit. `2.` Data doesn't "flow" from the Active Directory database, except in the case of replication from one Domain Controller to another. `3.` How is it that you've been tasked with this when you obviously have such a fundamental misunderstanding of Active Directory, Exchange Server and SharePoint? No offense intended.

Comment: Having a difficult time understanding your question which leads me to believe that you may not have enough expertise for this task. Nevertheless: AD contains data used for user management by Exchange and Sharepoint. However, Exchange and Sharepoint have their own data as well kept off of AD. ADUC is the GUI you would use to modify user attributes, group memberships and such that are stored in AD.

Comment: My main question was whether AD and Exchange were the same data, which I didn't think was true. I don't have the expertise to do this on my own, this information is coming from the person tasked with giving me the data so I can make the graphic. I do have a limited understanding of AD and Exchange. AD houses data. Exchange can access the data as well as create new records in AD but AD never 'pushes' to Exch. My SharePoint example was just an example of the kind of thing I am creating. My main question is whether AD and Exchange are the same data table

Comment: Almost all user info is in AD, even the Exchange attributes. They're not always attributes of the user object however. Without more specific examples of your question, we'll have a difficult time giving you answers that are both useful and correct.

Comment: Assuming you are on at least Exchange 2003, then, yes, it uses AD as its directory service.

Comment: Thank you, that does answer my question guys. I'm trying to create a simple diagram for people some of which probably have never heard of AD before.